# PHP lost variables on include

Tags: php, server, host

The project I wrote works on my computer (using `XAMPP`) and on my `Linux` server (using `Apache2`), both of them use `PHP7`.

My friend will host it on his existing `1&1 Host` and also use `PHP7`. And that is the only host where it does not work.

The site works as so: `index.php` will include the `php` file. But after include all variables and constants are lost. And that is a huge problem.

On the `pageTools.php` there should be many functions like `head()`. 
So if I open a page it shows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function head() in /homepages/35/d31536471/htdocs/SoWiHome/katalog/artikel.php:101 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/35/d31536471/htdocs/SoWiHome/katalog/artikel.php on line 101

index.php

```
<?php
define("BASE",__DIR__);
define("BASEURL", "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/".basename(__DIR__));
define("URL", BASEURL);
require BASE."/CONFIG.php";
require BASE."/pageTools.php";

ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("register_globals", 1); //Don't work. 
ini_set("error_log", __DIR__."/log.txt");

session_start();

$openURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if ( strpos($openURL, "?") )
    $openURL = strtok($openURL, "?");
$aOpen = explode("/", $openURL );
$baseUrl = BASEURL;

$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die("Fehler bei der Datenbankverbindung!");
$db->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

global $openURL, $baseUrl, $db; //Also don't work...

if ($openURL == "" or $openURL == "/") {
    include "home.php";
    exit;
}
elseif (end($aOpen) == "admin") {
    include BASE."/admin.php";
    die;
}
elseif (file_exists(BASE."/".strtolower($aOpen[2]).'.php')) {
    include BASE."/".strtolower($aOpen[2]).'.php';
}
else {
    echo "<!--TRY: ".json_encode($aOpen)."-->";
    include "error404.php";
}
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /katalog
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that `register_globals` are no longer supported in PHP7.

From PHP.net:

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
>
> Perhaps the most controversial change in PHP is when the default value for the PHP directive register_globals went from ON to OFF in PHP » 4.2.0. Reliance on this directive was quite common and many people didn't even know it existed and assumed it's just how PHP works. This page will explain how one can write insecure code with this directive but keep in mind that the directive itself isn't insecure but rather it's the misuse of it.

Find more about `register_globals` on the [PHP.net - Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)